# Batch faulting in a to-many relationship for a collection of objects

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

**Scenario:**

Let's say I have an entity called `Author` that has a to-many relationship called `books` to the `Book` entity (inverse relationship `author`). If I have an existing collection of `Author` objects, I want to fault in the `books` relationship for all of them in a single fetch request.

**Code**

This is what I've tried so far:

```
NSArray *authors = ... // array of `Author` objects
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Book"];
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author IN %@", authors];
```

Executing this fetch request does not result in the `books` relationship of the objects in the `authors` array being faulted in (inspected via logging).

I've also tried doing the fetch request the other way around:

```
NSArray *authors = ... // array of `Author` objects
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Author"];
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", authors];
fetchRequest.relationshipKeypathsForPrefetching = @[@"books"];
```

This doesn't fire the faults either. What's the appropriate way of going about doing this?

Comment: What is your actual problem. Why do you require everything to be loaded into memory at the same time?

Comment: Because firing faults on the `books` property on each individual `Author` object results in a bunch of cache misses when everything could be coalesced into a single fetch.

Comment: How about `setPropertiesToFetch:`?

Comment: Documentation states that `propertiesToFetch` only applies to `NSDictionaryResultType`, not `NSManagedObjectResultType`.

Comment: I guess `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` should do the trick, if it does work with to-many relationships as it should..

Comment: Not sure how you can benefit from faulting object on fetch because a fault object is basically a placeholder. CoreData still need to fetch it property values from cache or from back store upon first access, at which point it then become realized object. It only make sense when you already hold a realized object and you wanted to refresh it.

Comment: Have you tried using subquery?